# Codeblocks não compila o código no GNU/Linux Debian

Tags: c, compilação, linux, codeblocks

Instalei o code blocks no meu debian mas eles não está compilando. Suspeitei que fosse algum problema de compatibilidade com o GCC, então compilei no terminal e então ele gerou o arquivo .o
Tentei jogar o arquivo main.o pra pasta  obj/debug, porém, quando executei na IDE, ele me retornou só uma tela preta sem absolutamente nada que eu tinha codado. Alguém aí conseguiria dar uma força?
segue abaixo imagens do procedimento:[image: Esse era o erro]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Experimente remover o parâmetro `-c`.

Answer (score -2):

Veja o erro que está dando:

**Error: No input files** -> **sem arquivos de entrada**

O compilador não está encontrando seu arquivo **main.c**

**Importante:**

*1 - Por questão de evitar algum eventual conflito com outro arquivo, recomendo fortemente dar outro nome para o seu arquivo com C, que não **main.c***.

*2 - O problema também pode ser de não ter caracteres ASCII no caminho do seu arquivo.
Veja mais detalhes aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781947/how-to-fix-no-input-files-in-codeblocks-code-c

Exemplo de um caminho adequado para seu arquivo: **/home/nome_de_usuario/Programas/main.c***

*Mas como a pergunta ficou bastante vaga, vamos começar do zero...*

Maneira adequada de instalar o Codeblocks no Debian 10 e 11:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install codeblocks codeblocks-contrib gcc g++ xterm
```

**codeblocks-contrib** -> instala os plugins básicos para serem usados no Codeblocks ( mais detalhes dos plugins: https://reposcope.com/package/codeblocks-contrib e [Package: codeblocks-contrib](https://packages.debian.org/buster/codeblocks-contrib) )

**gcc** -> instala o compilador gcc

**g++** -> instala o compilador g++

**xterm** -> terminal padrão de saída no Codeblocks (Debian e derivados).

Obs: Caso queira mudar o terminal de saída dos códigos no Codeblocks, vá em `Settings -> Environment` e `Terminal to launch console programs` e selecione o terminal que desejar. Recomendo o *gnome-terminal*, que pode ser instalado com esse comando:

```
& sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

Instalando o Codeblocks dessa forma, inicie o mesmo e crie um novo arquivo:
`File -> New -> Empty File` ou use as teclas de atalho `Ctrl + Shift + n` para isso
. Salve o arquivo em sua pasta pessoal **/home/** ou outra sub-pasta da sua home e escreva o código em C que desejar.
Segue um exemplo simples para testar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf("Código para teste!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compile e rode o programa

`Ctrl + F9` -> para compilar o programa

`Ctrl + F10` -> para executar o programa

Veja se o erro persiste ou não.

Caso persistir, dê um **reset** no Codeblocks para as configurações originais, tal como quando foi instalado,  com esse comando:

```
$ rm -r ~/.config/codeblocks/
```

Inicie o Codeblocks e vá em `File -> Open`, encontre seu programa "**main.c**", dê dois cliques no mesmo, compile e rode o programa para ver se resolve

Outra maneira de resolver o problema, mas não a ideal, é ir até onde está seu arquivo "**main.c**" e clicar com o botão direito nesse arquivo e em "**abrir com outra aplicação**" e abra o arquivo com o Codeblocks. Compile e rode o programa.

Caso queira compilar o programa como esse que você postou pelo terminal, com o nome de **main.c**, seria isso:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
```

E para rodar o programa pelo terminal:

```
$ ./main
```

Favor editar a pergunta, com informações da versão do Debian que usa, maneira como instalou o Codeblocks e a versão do Codeblocks.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).